# Why dynamic web project in eclipse indicating unexpected errors

Tags: java, eclipse-oxygen

I have a Dynamic Web Project in eclipse Oxygen,

It is showing error icon on java-resources folder,

and

showing error icon on web-content folder indicating the errors like jsps, javascripts etc..

[image: please see the image]

Could you please suggest me what's wrong with it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can exclude some directories from inspection

Comment: like what? could you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

- Try `Project > Clean > Clean All Projects` and now check if you are still getting errors. Sometimes a simple refresh is requires.
- Also are you able to successfully run the web project? If yes, then no issues. Just restart Eclipse.
- If it is a Maven or a Gradle Project, appropriate dependencies must be added.
- If a simple web projects then the related jar files might be missing.